# How to change JWT Token after adding new claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt, token, claims

I have a code below that adds a new claim

```
    public ActionResult AddClaim()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = User;
            var userIdentity = user.Identities.First();
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("myCustomClaim", "value of claim"));

            return View("Secure");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The claim was successfully added when using the function AddClaim().

[image]

[image]

However, when I decrypt the id_token in jwt.io, the claim that I recently added was not included in the payload. I have tried calling HttpContext.SigninAsync() but it does nothing.

My goal is to add the custom claim in the JWT Token payload. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The jwt is deserialized during authorization into the current user identity. Any claims you add are added to the user identity but not the JWT. Creation of a JWT is a complex process (usually) involving signatures and will need to be completely regenerated from scratch once you add another claim.

If you do not control the code that created the original JWT then you cannot do this. You could create your own new JWT with the user identity claims and then add your new one(s) but in most cases, you should not be adding claims to an existing token - the token usually comes from an authoritative server.